# how to upload file of size 500 MB or more in ASP.net aplication

Tags: c#, asp.net

Please let me know the possible ways of uploading a large file (say 500 MB excel File) in an ASP.net application. This was asked in an interview and I have no idea on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check the `HttpRuntimeSection.MaxRequestLength Property`

By default value is `4096 KB (4 MB)`.

I would recommend you to set your desired value in app web.config

The maximum value is: `2,147,483,647 bytes`

Insert it in the configuration/system.web section:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="524288000" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Check [HttpRuntimeSection.MaxRequestLength Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.maxrequestlength.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If it was an interview question they're either after some specific technical knowledge (i.e. the setting of the MaxRequestLength parameter) or they're after some more architectural answer - e.g. it would be better to upload the file in chunks and give the user feedback with a progress bar etc. In this case, a js solution (such as FineUploader) would be more appropriate.